# iOS dynamic application flow control by back end

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, config

I am working on application which is live on App Store.

Now we have new things to introduce in application which is way more different than current flow.

> We would like to control application flow by back end (Service based). I mean the idea here is to get a config file (XML more preferably) using service call on start of the application. And application will show dashboard or charts or pages based on this file.

The config file contains `dashboard details`, `parameter details`, `field details` etc. In short everything what needs to be there as like in static app.

We know how to do this, but questions here are:

1. Does it sound feasible
2. Does it approved by App Review Team?
3. Is there any other workaround?

I know this kind of questions are avoided in SO, but I am helpless now.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there is nothing wrong with this approach but make sure that you are handling every exception related to `UI`.

I mean as you said in your question that your `UI` goes as per `xml` that you got in response (`as i understand from question`), now consider a case that you not got response or xml for any reason then you have to manage this kind of situation. for example in this case you can display that no data to show in label etc!! Second thing your main thread should not be block because you are getting response from server and your `UI` depends on it.

So, you should take care of this kind of stuff and it is feasible! :)

Comment: Yes, for that I will manage a default config file, that file will be use if remote file is not available (in case no internet or server down).

Comment: Does it approved by Apple? that is what I am really desperate to know :)

Comment: No one can surely say that app will approve or not because it's depends on many thing. but as per my knowledge and  if you follow all guidelines then definitely your app will be accepted!!! Second thing, I have submitted similar kind of app as you asking in question in past!!

Answer (score 1):

You should consult the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) if you have not done so already.

That being said, asking "Will X be approved for the App Store?" is a bit of a crapshoot sometimes. What gets approved for one app doesn't always pass in another. Sometimes you get rejected in one version for something that was approved in a previous version. Reviewers follow the same guidelines, but they are human, after all. The best you can do is read the docs and do your best to follow the guidelines.